# Application failed codesign verification. The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate

Tags: ios, iphone, codesign

So I'm not new to codesigning with Apple. I understand this is a novice part of app development, but I'm getting this error and I can't solve it.  I understand that I create a private key through keychain access, use that private key to generate a certificate, use that certificate and an appID to generate a provisioning profile, and use an "App Store" profile to codesign for distribution.  But I think I'm running into this error because of xcode 4.2.  But this is what I've done to try and resolve this issue:

1. Uninstalled xcode using uinstall-devtools --mode=all, then rebooted and reinstalled xcode 4.0.2.
2. Removed and re-downloaded the certificate from the provision portal. (No invalid errors)
3. Removed all profiles associated with the appID I'm working with and only re-downloaded the App Store Distribution profile.
4. I made sure the I'm explicitly selecting the correct provisioning profile in the project and the target settings for release.
5. I'm making sure that the release setting is selected for "Archiving" in the Scheme.

One thing that I can think of that might be the issue is I'm targeting iOS version 4.2, and the base sdk is 4.3.

But I've been through Apple's doc: https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933

My issues started to happen after I installed xcode 4.2, and then went back to 4.0.2.

One other weird thing, is when I build for ad hoc I get the same warning, but the ad hoc build works.  It just seems that I can't submit to the app store while ignoring the warning.

Comment: You're more likely to get a better answer by Googling this. I've had a few code signing problems before, and Google turned up some pretty interesting solutions.

Comment: I am not sure whats your problem, but I can tell you for sure it's not your xcode version. I was able to do that with each beta version of the new xcode. I would erase all the keys from the keychain and redo everything from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a long pain staking process I finally got xcode to code sign with out the warning.  But before I tell you how I solved it, I'm going to tell you what I've done.

I cleared out all my public/private keys, cleared all certificates, uninstalled xcode 4.0.2, reinstalled xcode 4.2 (tried redoing certificates), uninstalled xcode 4.2, installed xcode 4.0.2 (tried redoing certificates), and after all that, still no luck.

Finally I deleted the WWDR certificate from my local machine and downloaded a new certificate from the provisioning portal, and YATZEE!  After I redid the certificates and provisioning profile, it finally built without a warning!

So just so anyone has to go through this I've decided to post my answer. I hope I help someone...

Answer (score 0):

You can not run build on your device with "app Store" Provisioning profile. to run on your device you need to have "ad hoc" provisioning profile.

To test or debug your build you need development provisioning profile.That also "ad hoc". for this also you need to create development certificate with same private key.

If you want to do the submission build you need to use "app store" distribution provisioning profile. do not try to install that build in your device it will not work. with "App store" distribution provisioning profile you can install only if its in itunes store or app store.

Hope this will help you.